# navbar-fixed-top cancels .container centering

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Why does twitter bootstrap's `navbar-fixed-top` or `navbar-fixed-bottom` makes a navbar full width and cancels the effect of `.container` which centers a navbar? See code below

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-full navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Please could you post all the css?  The issue appears to be due to conflicting css rules, so we'd need to see it :)

Comment: Without the `.container` the nav also not centering. http://jsbin.com/kovise/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add your container class to nav element?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-full navbar-dark bg-inverse container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
 </nav>
```

I guess it should help a little and if you add your own class like text-center with css: text-align:center; that should help you :)

Comment: this only centers the a tag within the navbar

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to make it work by adding the class `container` inside the `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`

This is how my code looks like.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can see it working here:
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVpJLG)